# systemd socket activation keeps respawning my service unit

Tags: devops, systemd

I have a "gameserver.socket" and a "gameserver.service".

The service gets activated by systemd socket activation on first connection.

My issue is the following:

If I stop the "gameserver.service", it will get spawned immediately by "gameserver.socket".

Why this happens ?

Should not the "gameserver.socket" get back to "listening" mode, rather than "running" mode and when another connection is being made, then it should start the "gameserver.service" ?

Answer (score 0):

your program needs to be compatible with socket activation
…

> Note that the daemon software configured for socket activation with
> socket units needs to be able to accept sockets from systemd, either
> via systemd's native socket passing interface (see sd_listen_fds(3)
> for details about the precise protocol used and the order in which the
> file descriptors are passed) or via traditional inetd(8)-style socket
> passing (i.e. sockets passed in via standard input and output, using
> StandardInput=socket in the service file).

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html